# The `.pipe()` method has deprecated in Gulp/Vinyl, but what it the alternative?

Tags: node.js, gulp, vinyl

> ```js
>     /**
>      * @deprecated This method was removed in v2.0.
>      * If file.contents is a Buffer, it will write it to the stream.
>      * If file.contents is a Stream, it will pipe it to the stream.
>      * If file.contents is null, it will do nothing.
>      */
>     pipe<T extends NodeJS.WritableStream>(
>         stream: T,
>         opts?: {
>             /**
>              * If false, the destination stream will not be ended (same as node core).
>              */
>             end?: boolean | undefined;
>         }
>     ): T; }
> ```
>
> [@types/vinyl v2.0.7](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@types/vinyl)

Because of it, many previously valid Gulp pipelines has become alerted.
No need to read the code in the below picture - it actual only for my project, I just want to show which troubles this deprecation could cause:

[image]

If I must to paste the code sample, just below one will be enough for the reproduction:

```
Gulp.src([]).pipe();
```

> Deprecated: This method was removed in v2.0. If file.contents is a
> Buffer, it will write it to the stream. If file.contents is a Stream,
> it will pipe it to the stream. If file.contents is null, it will do
> nothing

Fine, what we should to do now?
I don't think that the arbitrary pipeline could be replaced with Gulp `series` and `parallel`s.

Comment: From what I can tell, `.pipe` as a custom method on non-streams was [removed from Vinyl way back in 2016](https://github.com/gulpjs/vinyl/issues/107), the `pipe` on Gulp streams is still around (because that's inherited from Streams). Could this be an issue with your editor config as in [this comment](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/issues/31561#issuecomment-449392797)?

Comment: @ZacAnger, Thank you for the comment. Unfortunately, I have not understood how to fix the alert in `Gulp.src([]).pipe();`.  The code sample `if (file.isStream()) { file.contents = file.contents.pipe(transform()); }` posted in the issue seems to be unrelated with `Gulp.src([]).pipe();`.

Comment: What I'm saying is that it looks like this is an issue with your editor and its TypeScript configuration, not with Gulp itself. `gulp.src('/some/*glob.js').pipe(gulp.dest('some-destination/'))` is still completely valid. What was removed was a little-used `pipe` method from Vinyl, but that doesn't affect pipe working in general.

Comment: @ZacAnger, I see. Sound like the new bug ticket for the IntelliJ IDEA.